# canvas draw image and touch event?

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, canvas, touch

I am trying to wrote an app using phonegap and jquerymobile.
My app draw 4 image from a Image array and when i touch on 1 image, 1 page is called to display the image in full screen, but it's dont draw like i want and just 2 images is display in another page, other images is still don't display.
Please, check my code and tell me what wrong i am. 
thanks for read.
this is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>ListApp</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <style>
        img.fullscreen {
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
        }       
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    var drawCanvasImage = function (ctx,grid,row,x,y,w,h) {
        return function() {
//          window.alert('row:' + row);
            ctx.drawImage(grid[row], x, y,w,h);
        }
    }
    var sizedWindowWidth = ($(window).width() - 34);
    var sizedWindowHeight = ($(window).height() - 34);
    var r1=0;
    var r2=0;
    var mag = ["img/a1.png","img/a2.png","img/a3.png","img/a4.png","img/a5.png"];
    var grid = new Array();
    var sImg = new Array();

    $("#canvas1").width(sizedWindowWidth);
    $("#canvas1").height(sizedWindowWidth*3/10);
    $("#canvas2").width(sizedWindowWidth);
    $("#canvas2").height(sizedWindowWidth*1/10);
    $("#canvas3").width(sizedWindowWidth);
    $("#canvas3").height(sizedWindowWidth*3/10);
    $("#canvas4").width(sizedWindowWidth);
    $("#canvas4").height(sizedWindowWidth*1/10);
    $("#canvas5").width(sizedWindowWidth/2 - 10);
    $("#canvas5").height(sizedWindowWidth*1/10);
    $("#canvas6").width(sizedWindowWidth/2 - 10);
    $("#canvas6").height(sizedWindowWidth*1/10);
    $("#canvas7").width(sizedWindowWidth/2 - 10);
    $("#canvas7").height(sizedWindowWidth*1/10);
    $("#canvas8").width(sizedWindowWidth/2 - 10);
    $("#canvas8").height(sizedWindowWidth*1/10);

    var canvas1 = $("#canvas1").get(0);
    var canvas2 = $("#canvas2").get(0);
    var canvas3 = $("#canvas3").get(0);
    var canvas4 = $("#canvas4").get(0);

    if(canvas1 && canvas2 && canvas3 && canvas4)
    {
        var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
        var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
        var ctx3 = canvas3.getContext('2d');
        var ctx4 = canvas4.getContext('2d');

        if(ctx1 && ctx2 && ctx3 && ctx4)
        {
            ctx1.canvas.width  = sizedWindowWidth;
            ctx1.canvas.height = sizedWindowWidth*3/10;
            ctx2.canvas.width  = sizedWindowWidth;
            ctx2.canvas.height = sizedWindowWidth*1/10;
            ctx3.canvas.width  = sizedWindowWidth;
            ctx3.canvas.height = sizedWindowWidth*3/10;
            ctx4.canvas.width  = sizedWindowWidth;
            ctx4.canvas.height = sizedWindowWidth*1/10;

            $("#canvasDraw").click(function(){

                for(var r=0;r<2;r++) {

                        var x = 0;
                        var y = r*sizedWindowWidth/2;
                        var w = sizedWindowWidth/2 - 5;
                        var h = sizedWindowWidth*3/10;
                        sImg[r] = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+0);;
                        grid[r] = new Image();
                        grid[r].onload = drawCanvasImage(ctx1,grid,r,y,x,w,h);
                        ctx2.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
                        ctx2.fillRect(y, x, w, h/3);
                        ctx4.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
                        ctx4.fillRect(y, x, w, h/3);
                        grid[r].src = mag[sImg[r]];

                }
                for(var d=0;d<2;d++) {

                    var x = 0;
                    var y = d*sizedWindowWidth/2;
                    var w = sizedWindowWidth/2 - 5;
                    var h = sizedWindowWidth*3/10;
                    sImg[d+2] = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+0);;

                    grid[d] = new Image();
                    grid[d].onload = drawCanvasImage(ctx3,grid,d,y,x,w,h);
                    grid[d].src = mag[sImg[d+2]];
                }

                for (var j=0;j<mag.length;j++) {
                    if(sImg[0] == j){
                        $('#img1').attr("src",mag[j]);
                    }

                    if(sImg[1] == j){
                        $('#img2').attr("src",mag[j]);
                    }

                    if(sImg[2] == j){
                        $('#img3').attr("src",mag[j]);
                    }

                    if(sImg[3] == j){
                        $('#img4').attr("src",mag[j]);
                    }
                }

            });
            document.getElementById("mycanvas").addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, false);
            document.getElementById("mycanvas").addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, false);
            document.getElementById("mycanvas").addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, false);
            var x;
            var y;

            function touchHandler(e) {
              if (e.type == "touchstart") {
                  console.log("touch start! x: " + x + "y: " + y);
                  e.preventDefault();
                  x = event.touches[0].pageX;
                  y = event.touches[0].pageY;
                  if (x>10 && x<150 && y>10 && y<140) {
                      $('#anh1').show();
                  }
                  if (x>166 && x<298 && y>10 && y<140) {
                      $('#anh2').show();
                  }
                  if (x>16 && x<150 && y<190 && y>265) {
                      $('#anh3').show();
                  }
                  if (x>166 && x<298 && y<190 && y>265) {
                      $('#anh4').show();
                  }

              } else if (e.type == "touchmove") {
                  console.log("touch move!");
                  e.preventDefault();
              } else if (e.type == "touchend" || e.type == "touchcancel") {
                  console.log("touch end!");
                  e.preventDefault();
              }
            }
        }
    }

    $('#showimg1').click(function(){
        $('#anh1').hide();
        $('#mainpage').show();
    });
    $('#showimg2').click(function(){
        $('#anh2').hide();
        $('#mainpage').show();
    });
    $('#showimg3').click(function(){
        $('#anh3').hide();
        $('#mainpage').show();
    });
    $('#showimg4').click(function(){
        $('#anh4').hide();
        $('#mainpage').show();
    });
});
</script>

<div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Ghep Tranh Tu</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" id="mycanvas" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    <canvas id="canvas1" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;margin:0;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;margin:0;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas3" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;margin:0;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas4" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;margin:0;"></canvas>
</div>    
    <ul id="wordstore" style="text-align:center;border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
        <ul style="text-align:center;border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
            <li style="display:inline;border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"><canvas id="canvas5"></canvas></li>
            <li style="display:inline;border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"><canvas id="canvas6"></canvas></li>
            <li style="display:inline;border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"><canvas id="canvas7"></canvas></li>
            <li style="display:inline;border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"><canvas id="canvas8"></canvas></li>
        </ul>   
        <ul style="text-align:right;border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
            <li style="display:inline;border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"><input id="canvasDraw" type="button" value="New Game"/></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="anh1">
<header data-role="header">
    <a id="showimg1" href="#" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Photos</a>
</header>
<img id="img1" src="img/a14.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
</div><!-- Page Dog -->

<div data-role="page" id="anh2">
<header data-role="header">
    <a id="showimg2" href="#" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Photos</a>
</header>
<img id="img2" src="img/a14.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
</div><!-- Page Gummy Bears --> 

<div data-role="page" id="anh3">
<header data-role="header">
<a id="showimg3" href="#" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Photos</a>
</header>
<img id="img3" src="img/a14.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
</div><!-- Page Gummy Bears --> 

<div data-role="page" id="anh4">
<header data-role="header">
<a id="showimg4" href="#" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Photos</a>
</header>
<img id="img4" src="img/a14.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
</div><!-- Page Gummy Bears --> 

</body>
</html>
```

i fixed it! :D my fail at " y<190 && y>265"
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Consider answering your question below in answers section than updating the question itself.